# Unappear data from database in data grid view vb.net Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, connection, database-connection

I want to appear field from my table database to data grid view [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/656Ln.png) but not success.
my data from table unappear in data grid view [this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6XDN.png)

okey i want to show my script

this is my module script connection

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Module module_koneksi
    Public conn As OleDbConnection
    Public cmd As OleDbCommand
    Public ds As DataSet
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
    Public da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public lokasidata As String

```
Public Sub konek()
    lokasidata = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=db_access.mdb"
    conn = New OleDbConnection(lokasidata)
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

and this is my mudule form

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    konek()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tb_biodata", conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "tb_biodata")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tb_biodata")
    da.Dispose()
    ds.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

So help me to appear database in grid view !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `DataPropertyName` of Column is column name of datatable. Reference image :
[image]

Comment: in my colums collection nothing fill here.

Comment: [nothing option in data grid view properties][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9IAJH.png

Comment: Click button Add , and set Name, DataPropertyName , Header Text

Comment: [nothing DataPropertyName in option type][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dLYxf.png

Comment: hic. Click Add columns -> close, and select it